# Val of Select = null, if values is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Select and all values is disabled, how can I set the value to this Select?

```
<select id="testselect">
   <option disabled>1</option>
   <option disabled>2</option>
   <option disabled selected="selected">3</option>
</select>

alert($("#testselect").val()); //result null
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8x4h6ao0/)

Comment: use `$("#testselect option:selected")` look here https://jsfiddle.net/arjqk00f/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This ==>

```js
alert($('#testselect option[disabled]:selected').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<select id="testselect">
  <option disabled>1</option>
  <option disabled>2</option>
  <option disabled selected>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to be specific about value of which element to return.

```js
alert($("#testselect option:selected").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="testselect">
  <option disabled>1</option>
  <option disabled>2</option>
  <option disabled selected>3</option>
</select>
```